# SOAP XML Generated vs Manual

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm having a problem with an API that uses SOAP. My client is written in PHP and produces the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://webportal.gb.co.uk/GBPortal" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:CreateAuthenticatedSession xsi:type="ns1:CreateAuthenticatedSession">
         <szUsername xsi:type="xsd:string">...</szUsername>
         <szPassword xsi:type="xsd:string">...</szPassword>
      </ns1:CreateAuthenticatedSession>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The reference XML in the documentation is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CreateAuthenticatedSession xmlns="http://webportal.gb.co.uk/GBPortal">
      <szUsername>string</szUsername>
      <szPassword>string</szPassword>
    </CreateAuthenticatedSession>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Which as far as I can see is functionally the same.

Are there any differences I've missed that would result in the API rejecting the XML? Would prefer not to have to work around by using string concatenation to generate the XML.

*Edit:* If there are no functional differences, then please leave an answer.

Comment: I do not think the XML is rejected. I think you do not get the expected response back (even an error is a valid response). So unless you specify as well the concrete problem (expected vs. actual response), it is hard to answer your question. Technically the XML is the same, but in your concrete case we know from your question that there is a difference in your usage-scenario.

Comment: @hakre the response is irrelevant, I just need to know if the XML is functionally the same so I know if it is a problem my end or the API (i.e if I am okay to complain to the API owner). The actual issue is my XML triggers a internal server error on the API.

Comment: Well as written, on that level it seems identical. However, your client adds the `xsi:type` attributes. I don't think that this causes an issue, however, it is a difference (the other differences are actually none, they are only using different prefixes but all those different prefixes are standing for the same namespaces so they are technically identical even their prefix-name is different). Still I guess the problem remains that you are triggering the internal server error. Most likely the SOAP server is actually not XML conform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two requests are functionally the same. The one generated by your client just uses a different namespace name for the `<Envelop>` and `<Body>`, but this still points to the same namespace as the documentation version (`http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`).

Also your client version uses a namespace on the `CreateAuthenticatedSession` element, whereas the documentation version just declares the `xmlns` attribute instead.

Comment: Thanks, so there is no valid reason why the API should reject the XML?

Comment: I can't see any reason. Is your version built by the native SoapClient that reads the server's WSDL? If so, I would be pretty confident that the request is fine.